# Text Editor like Pages iPad App

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to implement a functionality similar to found in Pages app..i.e. text floating around images, image zooming etc.. I have been struggling with this part of my application but no success yet. Would be grateful if someone provides me with some pointers in this regard , like 'Which UIControl should I use?','Help in thinking logic' etc..

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a fun app to develop.

Some Pointers:

- Immediately off the bat, I would say look into creating your own Controls for the floating objects.
- I would suggest tackling a smaller project, or maybe a few small to medium size projects. p
- Try making a few apps with WinForms or WPF. Also look into XSL:FO.

Immediately off the bat, I would say look into creating your own Controls.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on 'Own Controls'. Do you mean like subclassing UItextView or UIScrollView or any other control and adding some stuff into it..??

Comment: Create your own custom user controls.

Answer (score 0):

There was a WWDC session that talked about iOS text. I don't think it's violating NDA to say this is going to be a very hard project. No, make that very, very, very hard.

You will probably need to do **all** UI yourself, and use Core Text for rendering of the text. (But I believe you need to draw selection, etc.) And do the layout yourself.